# How should this exception be handled better in java?

Tags: java, exception

So I'm writing this code (see below) and my teacher says it is bad practice just to make a `System.out.println`, and I should do something else to handle the exception better. But how?

```
public static List<Highscore> readHighScoreTable(String fileName) {
    //creates a new ArrayList of highscores.
    List<Highscore> result = new ArrayList<Highscore>();
    try {
        //creates a new bufferedReader that reads from the file. 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line = null;
        //a loop that reads through all the lines in the file.
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            //some code }
        reader.close();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        //If there is a problem, it prints a error message. 
        System.out.println("There was a problem reading your file.");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This depends very much on the context. For example is this part of a GUI program or used only on the command line?

Comment: Generally you `throw` the error.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. No GUI, just a simple text-based game.

Comment: Instead of saying "There was a problem", you should give more specific reason of error like file not found or malformed url or maybe unsupported encoding. Check java documentation of IOException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact you have broadly two ways of coping with an exception.
Catching it to let the execution goes on or propagating it to the caller.

Here you chose the first way :

```
catch(IOException ioe) {
    //If there is a problem, it prints a error message. 
    System.out.println("There was a problem reading your file.");
}
```

But you simply wrote a textual message in the output.
It is not enough. To get a valuable information, you need the whole stacktrace that contains the exception and the statement that provoked it.
You could write it in the error standard  : `ioe.printStackTrace()` or better using a logger.

Here you chose the first way (catching the exception) as you want to return the list even if at a time an `IOException` occured during `Scanner.readLine()`. 
In some cases, it may be acceptable.
In others, the requirement may be different and you don't want to recover from the exception. So you let it be propagated to the caller.
In this case the list will of course not be returned whatever elements added in.

Here is a version that propagates the exception to the caller.
Note that the inputstream should be closed in any case. 
So either do it in a `finally` statement or better yet, use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement that ensures the resource releasing.

```
public static List<Highscore> readHighScoreTable(String fileName) throws IOEexception {
    //creates a new ArrayList of highscores.
    List<Highscore> result = new ArrayList<Highscore>();    

    //creates a new bufferedReader that reads from the file. 
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))){
      String line = null;
      //a loop that reads through all the lines in the file.
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //some code 
      }
    }   
    return result;
}
```

And the code client :

```
try{
  List<Highscore> highScores =  readHighScoreTable("filename");
}
catch (IOException e){
   // log the exception
   // give a feeback to the user
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't catch the exception at all.

The method should add `IOException` to its `throws` clause to signal the caller that it's impossible to read the file that it provided. Just as `new FileReader()` throws an exception to tell you that it can't read that file.

That way,

1. The caller knows there is a problem, rather than getting an incorrect, but valid result (i.e. an empty list)
2. The caller can choose to signal the error to the user the way it needs to (a dialog in in a GUI, a message in a console application, a 500 error in a web application, etc.)
3. The caller can handle the exception the way it wants/needs to: try another file, retry later, log the error in a file, etc.

In short, if you can't handle an exception in a correct way because it's not your responsibility, you should not catch the exception. Or at least, if you catch it, you should throw another one, chained with the original exception.

The responsibility of the method here is to read and parse a file. It's not to handle the interaction with the user. So it should thus throw the exception until the code responsible for handling the interaction with the user can catch it and display the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you print some static string you can't understand later why & where exception occur

Use

```
ioe.printStackTrace();
```

> The java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace() method prints this throwable
>   and its backtrace to the standard error stream. It prints a stack
>   trace for this Throwable object on the error output stream that is the
>   value of the field System.err.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different things you can do:

- print the cause of the exception: `System.out.println("There was a problem reading your file, error:" + ioe.getMessage());`
- print the whole stacktrace (useful to developer, but not to end user): `ioe.printStackTrace();`
- return `null` as a signal to invoker that something went wrong (but you must document that)
- propagate the exception, but then mark that your method throws `IOException` and leave the exception handling to the invoker

If you choose to handle the exception yourself, make sure that you didn't leave the program in the corrupted state and that you clearly informed the invoker what happened. If you are not able or willing to do that, leave handling to the invoker.